# SLIM FRAMEWORK - 404 PAGE NOT FOUND

Tags: php, php-7, slim, slimframework, slimframwork

Olá, bom dia.

Eu estou tentando fazer uma rota usando SLIM e consigo normalmente acessar via URL e internamente(via menu) as paginas com o SLIM configurado, porém quando eu faço LOGIN no site, ele não manda para a página que foi requisitada. Por exemplo:

Quando eu efetuar login, deveria mandar para a página dashboard, mas isso não ocorre. Vai o código abaixo:

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['btnEnviar'])){
        $sql        = "SELECT id, login, senha, nome FROM usuario WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'";
        $consulta   = $conexao->consulta($sql);
        $row        = $conexao->busca($consulta);
        $total      = $conexao->conta($consulta);

        if($total == 1){
            $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
            $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
            //echo "<script language= 'JavaScript'> location.href='/dashboard'; </script>";
            header("Location: /dashboard");
        }else{
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            echo $alerta1;
        }

        $conexao->desconectar();
    }
```

**SLIM**

```
$app->get(
    '/login/',
    function () {
        require_once("login.php");
    }
);

$app->get(
    '/dashboard/',
    function () {
        require_once("dashboard.php");
    }
);
```

---

Eu já tentei diversas 'soluções', porém sem sucesso, como; chamar via POST ao invés de GET, alterar nome de página entre algumas outras.

URL de Login: http://127.0.0.1/edsa-moisesdesenvolvedorweb.com.br/admin/login (Ao acessar, ele continua nessa página, informado o erro 404)

URL que deveria acessar : http://127.0.0.1/edsa-moisesdesenvolvedorweb.com.br/admin/dashboard

Agradeço desde já a ajuda da comunidade!

Comment: qual versao do slim?

Comment: é a segunda versão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tudo bem? Desculpe a demora. consegui resolver seu problema, eu criei um repositório com as alterações https://github.com/gaoliveira21/stackoverflow-question , basicamente eu exclui a pasta do slim e instalei via composer, e criei um virtual host no xampp. pra fazer isso basta encontrar o arquivo httpd-vhosts.conf e adicionar  esse codigo

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@gmail.com.br
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\moises\minhapagina" #diretorio raiz do projeto
    ServerName www.minhapagina.com.br #url do site em localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\moises\minhapagina"> #diretorio raiz do projeto
        Require all granted

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

geralmente esse arquivo fica nesse diretorio C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra 
depois basta alterar o arquivo hosts que no windows fica em C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
adicionando este codigo

```
127.0.0.1       www.minhapagina.com.br #a mesma url que esta em ServerName no arquivo httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Gabriel!!!

Eu vou testar logo logo, mas vc saberia me explicar, pq não funcinou com a instalçaão do Slim normal.

Comment: Talvez algum problema com o autoload da classe, mas acredito que o principal problema era a questão da cofiguração do apache, ja que o slim necessita de uma configuração. voçê pode encontrar mais detalhes na documentação  http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html mas acredito que fosse esse o problema

Answer (score 0):

basta tirar a segunda barra na rota, por exemplo

```
    $app->get(
    '/login',
    function () {
        require_once("login.php");
    }
);

$app->get(
    '/dashboard',
    function () {
        require_once("dashboard.php");
    }
);
```

ou então você pode acessar essas rotas:

http://127.0.0.1/edsa-moisesdesenvolvedorweb.com.br/admin/login/

http://127.0.0.1/edsa-moisesdesenvolvedorweb.com.br/admin/dashboard.php/

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão.Eu fiz isso que vc informou, mas não funcionou tmb.

Eu retirei até o bloco do dashboard do SLIM e retornei o redirecionamento para dashboard.php, porém sem sucesso.

Ele continua mantendo o redirecionamento para ..admin/login ao invés de dashboard

Comment: Eu não sei se existe algum problema com o bloco de login, não estou entendo mais

Comment: você tem um repositório no github com o seu projeto?

Comment: Oi Grabriel, posso sim.

https://github.com/MoisesFausto/minhapagina/tree/master/admin

Só pra não ficar confuso pra vc não ficar perdendo tempo procurando, os aquivos que eu estou mexendo são esses:

admin/index.php
.
..controller/controller.php

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma olhada assim que chegar em casa.

Comment: Show, obrigado!

Comment: Olá Moises, publiquei outra resposta aqui já que a solução que eu encontrei acabou ficando um pouco extensa, espero que ajude.

Answer (score -2):

Pra ser sincero o codigo nao ta muito bom mas tenta fazer essas alteracoes

```
$app->get(
    '/login/',
    function () use ($app) {
        require_once("login.php");
    }
);
```

```
...
        if($total == 1){
            $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
            $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
            $app->response->redirect('/admin/dashboard');
...
```

Comment: Adir, de que forma vc acha que poderia melhorar o codigo ?

Comment: Pow, não deu certo não essa resolução :/